# Is Activity Must in the following scenario?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcast

Following is code of my AndroidManifest

// Broadcast Receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.broadcastreceivers.ApplicationInstalled" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="101" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIG_STR" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

// Launcher Activity

```
<activity
    android:name="com.activity.MasterActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I do not want to have Activity in my application so when I comment or remove the activity declaration part from my AndroidManifest.xml  it stops firing Broadcast Receiver events for signal changes. But when I declare the activity as above it works fine.

My question is why do we require Activity in the project ?

Edit : I am using Android 2.3.3 version at present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue:**

Starting with 3.1 when applications are installed they are in a **`stopped`** state so they will not be able to run until the user explicitly launches them.

As a result, when applications are first installed, they are totally ignored by the system until and unless the user manually launches something: clicking on a launcher activity or adding an app widget, most likely.

Developers who had been relying upon getting some sort of system broadcast without user intervention will need to adjust their apps for Android 3.1 and higher versions.

**Explaination:**

As mentioned in your question,when you declare the `Activity` with above `<intent-filter>` , it will start the application , so now your application will be in `active` state instead of `stopped` state.That is why,now it will be able to receive the `broadcasts`

**Reference:**

[blogpost by CommonsWare](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Partially agree with you. But I have another project which monitors incoming SMS, it has only a broadcastreceiver and it is working very fine since around 2-3 months. However I learnt this new information from your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, just now I re-check that monitor application and it has Android 2.0 API set in it. I think that's why it is working. But the application I asked in the question is uses 2.3.3 version

Comment: @Vigbyor: are you testing your application on real device having version 2.3.3 ?

Comment: No, I am testing it on Samsung Galaxy Duos S-7562, Android version 4.0.4

Comment: @Vigbyor: version `4.0.4` is higher than `3.1` .so obviously you will face the issue. on the same device,test your old application which montiors incoming SMS . I am sure it won't work either.

Comment: Then how can you say that my sms monitor application will not run properly on Android 2.0 ?

Comment: @Vigbyor: I have told that it won't work `On the same device` means your `Samsung Galaxy Duos S-7562, Android version 4.0.4 `.It will work on devices having version less than `3.1`

Comment: But it is working fine since many days on my Galaxy Duos S-7562.

Comment: @Vigbyor: Go to `settings` ,force stop your application and then send an sms,it won't monitor.

Comment: After force stopping any app, How can you expect it to be work ?

Comment: @Vigbyor: it is the same state as mentioned by `CommonsWare` who is in development team of `Android OS`.

Comment: Sorry not agree with you on this part.

Comment: @Vigbyor: i am wondering how sms montior is really working on version 4.0.4 .kindly uninstall it and install again.then let me know if it works.it is really miracle for you if it is working.

Comment: Yes, I did that many times but it is working fine. Now I start wondering too. :P :P

Comment: @Vigbyor: if you don't mind,kindly post manifest file of both applications,I will try to find the reason behind this mystry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39802/discussion-between-vigbyor-and-mehul-joisar)

Comment: to your surprice, today it is working fine in my mobile as well, without any activity support :).

Comment: @Vigbyor: great !! would you like to sell your mysterious cell to me? lol